# global variable for the main class of the app

Tags: c++

https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blob/master/src/mumble/Global.h

```
#define g (*Global::g_global_struct)
```

Is this design one I could use? In mumble source, there's a global variable (a single one) `g` that is an instance of the main class of the app that encapsulates everything.

Is this case where `global variables are evil` doesn't apply? having a single global variable for the whole app like that?

In my case, I don't have any globals. However, my `main` app class, is used everywhere obviously and I'm currently using "Dependency Injection" but it doensn't seem feel right in my case. I could just have a `extern class gApp` in my header and include it everywhere.

Comment: I think there are acceptable use cases for globals, but having a global main class which is needed "everywhere" feels suspiciously after tight coupling which is bad ... but I haven't gone through your code.

Comment: Somewhere in this discussion the Singleton is going to appear. This is where programming and religion meet, so prepare for the worst...

Comment: Why not use a reference for `g` rather than a define?

Comment: @MicroVirus It's not my code, but if g was a reference, it would wouldn't work because g_global_struct would still be null. Unless it was extern, and the reference was initialized after the creation of the g_global_struct, which is impossible if you create that object in main (since you would have to initialize the reference in the global scope). And if you initialize both variables at global scope, then you can't use try/catch in case the constructor throws.

Comment: In that case, it would be a reference to `Global::g_global_struct` and you'd   use `g` as a pointer. Not saying it's necessarily better, but because macro's don't respect scope, any `g` in your source code could be overwritten by it, so that's why I'd prefer a reference, even if it's a pointer then.